# How to append to column respectively

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

I would like to append the new student fare in a new column under concession dataframe with the students(1200) having the same price while same adult price for national serviceman and adult(4050) and seniors(2070) and a last new column single trip with all having the same price(6900)?

I tried using iterrows but to no avail, are there any other possible methods?

Answer (score 0):

Update to add columns in the dataframe:
Initial step:

```
concession['Adult']=4050
concession['Senior']=2070
concession['Student']=1200
concession[ 'Single Trip']=6900
```

Step 1: Create a dataframe that contains the fares and their respective category:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fares = pd.DataFrame(data={'fare_category':['Adult','Senior','Student', 'Single Trip'],'fare':[4050,2070,1200,6900]})
```

Step 2: Create in the concession a new column named 'fare_category' based on whether they have a specific word included in the column 'card_holders' e.g. all values that contain the word 'Student' are assigned to the category 'Student' (the default value for the instances not encountered in any of the cases is 'Single Trip')

```
concession['fare_category'] = np.where(concession['card_holders'].str.contains('Student'),'Student',
     np.where(concession['card_holders'].str.contains('Adult'),'Adult',
              np.where(concession['card_holders'].str.contains('Senior'), 'Senior','Single Trip')))
```

Step 3: Merge the 2 dataframes (concession and fares) on the column fare_category so that we can add a specific fare to each category.

```
concession_combined_with_fare = concession.merge(fares, on='fare_category')
```

Comment: Sorry but i would need single trip to appeneded as a new column itself where evryonehas the same value(6900) and adult value used for adult and full time national servieman, is it possible for you to change the code that way?

Comment: I added an update in the (Initial step)